# Output from function in Node-Red showing as [object OBJECT] in html. template

Tags: javascript, html, object, converters, node-red

ok, it's my first day....

I'm trying to make a little Node-Red app. It might seem silly but its actually a fun example of something that I need to do that is a lot less humorous.
A HTTP Input triggers a HTTP Request to an Urban Dictionary API and scrapes random definitions for the term "Honey Badger".

Then a function chews the string to pieces and pulls out just the actual definition and discards all the meta junk.

The String is then passed to a template that contains a load of HTML before and after the {{payload}} line to produce a page that has the content from Urban Dictionary displayed, with a random definition displayed on each page load.

I'm getting everything that I want, and debugging the output of my template is showing the UD content in the log however in the browser all I'm getting is [object OBJECT] where my paragraph of text should be.

I understand that this is because the function is outputting an object, not a string.

I don't really have a full understanding of what an object is.

I've never, ever coded any JS before, this is where I'm starting from.

```
[{"id":"65001585.8c9564","type":"http in","z":"4737d790.fefe58","name":"badger","url":"/Badger","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":76,"y":72,"wires":[["980800c8.6789f","ab39736b.ffbfd"]]},{"id":"980800c8.6789f","type":"http request","z":"4737d790.fefe58","name":"URBAN DICTIONARY","method":"GET","ret":"txt","url":"https://urban.now.sh/random/Honey Badger","tls":"","x":269,"y":106,"wires":[["c0ff5132.822508"]]},{"id":"ab39736b.ffbfd","type":"http response","z":"4737d790.fefe58","name":"http response","x":1016.5551147460938,"y":75.22221374511719,"wires":[]},{"id":"e98c98a8.0a9a28","type":"template","z":"4737d790.fefe58","name":"Template","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<HTML>\n\n\t<HEAD>\n\t\t<TITLE> [ H O N E Y B A D G E R ] </TITLE>\n\t\t<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"300\">\n<style>\np.minortext\n{\n    font-family: \"Arimo\";\n    color:#A9A9A9\n}\np.majortext\n{\n    font-family: \"Impact\";\n    color:black\n    size:20\n}\n\n</style>\n</head>\n\n\t<BODY>\n\t        <CENTER>\n\t            <Table Width = \"100%\" Bgcolor=\"#A9A9A9\"><TR><TD ALIGN = \"CENTER\">\n\t              <a class=\"weatherwidget-io\" href=\"https://forecast7.com/en/n34d93138d60/adelaide/\" data-font=\"Roboto Slab\" data-mode=\"Current\" data-days=\"3\" data-shadow=\"#000000\" data-accent=\"#000000\" data-textColor=\"#ffffff\" data-highColor=\"#ffffff\" data-lowColor=\"#ffffff\" data-sunColor=\"#ffffff\" data-moonColor=\"#ffffff\" data-cloudColor=\"#ffffff\" data-cloudFill=\"#ffffff\" data-rainColor=\"#ffffff\" data-snowColor=\"#ffffff\" >Adelaide, South Australia, Australia</a>\n<script>\n!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=\"https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"weatherwidget-io-js\");\n</script>\n</td><td align = \"center\">\n\n\n</td>\n\n\n\n</TD><TD ALIGN = \"RIGHT\"><IMG SRC=\"LogIn.PNG\">       </TD></TR></Table>\n\t        <Table Width = \"500\" Height = \"620\" Border = \"0\">\n\t            <TR Width = \"500\" Height = \"320\">\n\t                <TD Width = \"500\" Height = \"320\" VALIGN = \"CENTER\">\n\t\t<CENTER>\n\t\t\t    <FONT SIZE = \"20\">\n                    <p class=\"majortext\">\n                        <IMG SRC=\"HoneyBadger.PNG \" ALT=\"HoneyBadger\"><BR>\n\t\t\t\t        <B>H O N E Y B A D G E R</B>\n\t\t\t        </P>\n\t\t\t    </FONT>\n\t\t\t        </TD>\n\t\t\t     </TR>\n\t\t\t     \t            <TR Width = \"500\" Height = \"300\">\n\t                <TD Width = \"500\" Height = \"300\" VALIGN = \"TOP\">\n\t\t\t<CENTER>\n\t\t\n\t\t\t<p class=\"minortext\">\n\t\t\t    \t\t\t    <FONT SIZE = \"5\">\n\t\t\t    {{{payload}}}\n            </P>\n\t\t</CENTER>\n\t\t    </TD>\n\t\t    </TR>\n\t\t    </TABLE>\n\t\t</CENTER>\n\t</BODY>\n</HTML>\t\t\t    \n\n","output":"str","x":830.0000610351562,"y":108.55557250976562,"wires":[["ad7d02ac.52565","ab39736b.ffbfd"]]},{"id":"ad7d02ac.52565","type":"debug","z":"4737d790.fefe58","name":"","active":true,"console":"true","complete":"payload","x":1013.3883666992188,"y":153.77764892578125,"wires":[]},{"id":"c0ff5132.822508","type":"function","z":"4737d790.fefe58","name":"test","func":"var parts = msg.payload.split(\"definition\");\nvar message1 = { payload: parts[0] };\nvar message2 = { payload: parts[1] };\nvar msg2parts = message2.payload.split(\"URL\");\nvar msgsparts1 = {payload: msg2parts[0]};\nvar msgsparts2 = {payload: msg2parts[1]};\n\n\nreturn msgsparts1;\n","outputs":"1","noerr":0,"x":446.75921630859375,"y":106.75926971435547,"wires":[["e132da2c.78b1a8"]]},{"id":"e132da2c.78b1a8","type":"change","z":"4737d790.fefe58","name":"","rules":[{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"\"\"","fromt":"str","to":"","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"\\n","fromt":"str","to":"","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"n\\","fromt":"str","to":"","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":":","fromt":"str","to":"","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"\"\"\"","fromt":"str","to":"","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":".\",\"\"","fromt":"str","to":"","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"\\","fromt":"str","to":"","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"\"","fromt":"str","to":"","tot":"str"},{"t":"change","p":"payload","pt":"msg","from":"example","fromt":"str","to":"","tot":"str"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":628.8887939453125,"y":107.99996948242188,"wires":[["e98c98a8.0a9a28"]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to remove the direct link between the `http-in` and the `http-response` node as this will just return nothing to the browser making the request.

Next problem, for http-in/http-response nodes to work you need to pass the original message generated by the `http-in` node all the way down the flow to the `http-response` node. You are generating a new message (`msgsparts1`) object in the `Test` function node, this will not work.

Also the response from urban dictionary is a JSON object so rather than try and chop it up using the String function .split() it's much easier to parse the JSON and just access it's fields. You can do this by using the `JSON node` to parse string and a `change node` to move the description to the msg.payload.

You also need to remove the headers from the `http-request` before sending the message to the `http-response`. You can do this with the same `change node`

```
[{"id":"72cc29ed.aa819","type":"http in","z":"8aa94366.b8bde","name":"badger","url":"/Badger","method":"get","swaggerDoc":"","x":90,"y":160,"wires":[["2f9e6174.bde466"]]},{"id":"2f9e6174.bde466","type":"http request","z":"8aa94366.b8bde","name":"URBAN DICTIONARY","method":"GET","ret":"txt","url":"https://urban.now.sh/random/Honey Badger","tls":"","x":200,"y":260,"wires":[["5d7d10da.a757d"]]},{"id":"c6b86250.24357","type":"http response","z":"8aa94366.b8bde","name":"http response","x":960,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"5d1bd9d2.9efad8","type":"template","z":"8aa94366.b8bde","name":"Template","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<HTML>\n\n\t<HEAD>\n\t\t<TITLE> [ H O N E Y B A D G E R ] </TITLE>\n\t\t<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"300\">\n<style>\np.minortext\n{\n    font-family: \"Arimo\";\n    color:#A9A9A9\n}\np.majortext\n{\n    font-family: \"Impact\";\n    color:black\n    size:20\n}\n\n</style>\n</head>\n\n\t<BODY>\n\t        <CENTER>\n\t            <Table Width = \"100%\" Bgcolor=\"#A9A9A9\"><TR><TD ALIGN = \"CENTER\">\n\t              <a class=\"weatherwidget-io\" href=\"https://forecast7.com/en/n34d93138d60/adelaide/\" data-font=\"Roboto Slab\" data-mode=\"Current\" data-days=\"3\" data-shadow=\"#000000\" data-accent=\"#000000\" data-textColor=\"#ffffff\" data-highColor=\"#ffffff\" data-lowColor=\"#ffffff\" data-sunColor=\"#ffffff\" data-moonColor=\"#ffffff\" data-cloudColor=\"#ffffff\" data-cloudFill=\"#ffffff\" data-rainColor=\"#ffffff\" data-snowColor=\"#ffffff\" >Adelaide, South Australia, Australia</a>\n<script>\n!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=\"https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"weatherwidget-io-js\");\n</script>\n</td><td align = \"center\">\n\n\n</td>\n\n\n\n</TD><TD ALIGN = \"RIGHT\"><IMG SRC=\"LogIn.PNG\">       </TD></TR></Table>\n\t        <Table Width = \"500\" Height = \"620\" Border = \"0\">\n\t            <TR Width = \"500\" Height = \"320\">\n\t                <TD Width = \"500\" Height = \"320\" VALIGN = \"CENTER\">\n\t\t<CENTER>\n\t\t\t    <FONT SIZE = \"20\">\n                    <p class=\"majortext\">\n                        <IMG SRC=\"HoneyBadger.PNG \" ALT=\"HoneyBadger\"><BR>\n\t\t\t\t        <B>H O N E Y B A D G E R</B>\n\t\t\t        </P>\n\t\t\t    </FONT>\n\t\t\t        </TD>\n\t\t\t     </TR>\n\t\t\t     \t            <TR Width = \"500\" Height = \"300\">\n\t                <TD Width = \"500\" Height = \"300\" VALIGN = \"TOP\">\n\t\t\t<CENTER>\n\t\t\n\t\t\t<p class=\"minortext\">\n\t\t\t    \t\t\t    <FONT SIZE = \"5\">\n\t\t\t    {{{payload}}}\n            </P>\n\t\t</CENTER>\n\t\t    </TD>\n\t\t    </TR>\n\t\t    </TABLE>\n\t\t</CENTER>\n\t</BODY>\n</HTML>\t\t\t    \n\n","x":780,"y":260,"wires":[["bc66ae55.037f78","c6b86250.24357"]]},{"id":"bc66ae55.037f78","type":"debug","z":"8aa94366.b8bde","name":"","active":true,"console":"true","complete":"payload","x":940,"y":300,"wires":[]},{"id":"5d7d10da.a757d","type":"json","z":"8aa94366.b8bde","name":"","x":390,"y":260,"wires":[["8ecda72f.12eed8"]]},{"id":"8ecda72f.12eed8","type":"change","z":"8aa94366.b8bde","name":"","rules":[{"t":"move","p":"payload.definition","pt":"msg","to":"payload","tot":"msg"},{"t":"delete","p":"headers","pt":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":560,"y":260,"wires":[["e0951766.77e858","5d1bd9d2.9efad8"]]},{"id":"e0951766.77e858","type":"debug","z":"8aa94366.b8bde","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":810,"y":180,"wires":[]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes the direct link was an error i made when clearing junk out so i could share something clean. The link previously went into the template node because for some reason passing the data to the template node from my change rule didnt serve up the template to the http response. This is my first toe dip with Node-Red so Im not sure if I can expect it to behave how I thought it would.

I really dont know anything about JSON so i stuck to how i would deal with a string in python, string.split ()

I'll revisit this with your suggestions in the morning.  Thankyou kindly for your help :)

Comment: You should be parsing the JSON in python as well, it's never a good idea to try and chop it up by hand.

Comment: Yes I'm a total noob. So despite the fact that my approach to pulling out the bit of data I wanted was incorrect, I'm still curious to know how to go about taking the output of a function and inserting it into a template to be sent for a http response. Is there a way i can do something like msg.payload=str(msg.payload)?